# Avoid loop when comparing two bytes32

Tags: solidity

So currently my function looks as follow:

```
 /**
   * @notice Checks if it is allowed to transition between the given states
   */
  function checkNextStates(bytes32 fromState, bytes32 toState) public view returns (bool hasNextState) {
    hasNextState = false;
    bytes32[] storage nextStates = states[fromState].nextStates;
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < nextStates.length; i++) {
      if (keccak256(abi.encodePacked(nextStates[i])) == keccak256(abi.encodePacked(toState))) {
        hasNextState = true;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
```

So fromState is a bytes32 of multiple values but toState is always the same length == 1. I pushed this to prod, when we have a lot in fromState then it becomes extremely costly. Do you guys have any idea on how to check if in a bytes32 with multiple values there is the value of a bytes32 with a single value?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an unsorted array you need somehow to apply a sorting / search algorithm;

This could be very expensive.

I would suggest to approach the problem differently, if possible (I have not clear what you are trying to achieve so this might not work):

---

instead of having an array of values, you could create a mapping
`mapping(bytes32 => bool)`where you save your
`keccak256(abi.encodePacked(toState))` as a key (and remove it when it is not needed anymore)

this would allow you to check the existence of the key you are looking for in O(1)